# Loop Through Tags in XML with PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML file that looks like this:

```
   <markerLat1>34.220986</markerLat1>
   <markerLon1>-112.745678</markerLon1>
   <markerHTML1>
      Text Goes Here
   </markerHTML1>

 <markerLat2>34.220986</markerLat2>
 <markerLon2>-112.745678</markerLon2>
   <markerHTML2>
       Text Goes Here
   </markerHTML2>
```

In my PHP script, I have the following:

```
for ($i=1;$i<=100;$i++){

$markerLat[$i] = $xml->markerLat[$i];
$markerLon[$i] = $xml->markerLon[$i];
$markerHTML[$i] = $xml->markerHTML[$i];

        if(strlen($markerLat[$i])>0){
        echo "L.marker([$markerLat[$i],$markerLon[$i]]).addTo(map).bindPopup($markerHTML[$i]);\n";
        }
}
```

This is not working. Any idea how I would achieve looping through the  tags in the xml file?

Thanks!

Comment: You're going to have to use something like `$xml->{"markerLat$i"}`

Comment: For reference: [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: That's not working, but I'll take a look through the link. Thanks.